# What to set 'sender' to in a GenericTinyMessage

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm using [TinyMessenger][1] successfully in my Mono For Android application, and am deriving my message classed from GenericTinyMessage so that I can sent content with them.

A GenericTinyMessage needs a Sender to be passed to the constructor, as described in the wiki:

```
// And if your message needs some "content" we provide a simple
// generic message (GenericTinyMessage<TContent>) out of the box.
//
// We can use that message directly or derive from it to gain a 
// strongly typed "content" property
public class MyMessageAgain : GenericTinyMessage<String>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new instance of the MyMessageAgain class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Message sender (usually "this")</param>
    /// <param name="content">Contents of the message</param>
    public MyMessageAgain(object sender, String content)
        : base(sender, content)
    {
        // We now have a public string property called Content
    }
}
```

*However*, I'm using this from a static class, and so don't have *this* to use for *sender*. Can I use *null*, or do I have to provide a sending object?

Thanks,

James

Comment: Common usage from a static class would be to pass in the type, ie `typeof(MyStaticClass)`, but ultimately, it depends on the user.

Comment: Thanks - as you say it really depends on the library, doesn't it? Checking the code for TinyMessenger, it will complain if I supply _null_, so typeof(MyStaticClass) looks like a good option.